# Django ManyToMany reverse query with specific key

Tags: django, postgresql, manytomanyfield

I have two tables. The first, is a basic user table. And the second is a table called Section.

```
def User(models.Model):
    ...
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...

def Section(models.Model):
    ...
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="teachers")
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="students")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ...
```

I would like to get all the student users (identified in the User table with `is_teacher=False`) which I know can be done easily with `User.objects.filter(is_teacher=False)`.

I would like to *also* get the active section(s) for each user.

But, at the moment, I can't even seem to get the set of *sections* for the users.

I've tried:

```
students = User.objects.filter(is_teacher=False)
for s in students:
    print s.section_set.all()
```

But I'm getting an error that `User` object has no `section_set`. I'm guessing because the section has two many to many relationships with the User table (teachers and students), I probably have to specify the relationship more clearly (to follow the students one not the teachers one). But I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When defining `related_name` value, keep in mind that this a name for *backwards* relation (in your case — from `User` to `Section`). So, to keep your code clear and easy to understand, I'd recommend you to change the names like this:

```
def Section(models.Model):
    ...
    teachers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="sections_where_teacher")
    students = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="sections_where_student")
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    ...
```

Then using the relations looks like this:

```
print s.sections_where_student.all()
```

Comment: Thanks. Starting to understand the real purpose of the related_names field now...

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
sec = Section.object.filter(students = students, is_active=True)
```

you will get the section objects for the students who is active.

Answer (score 0):

You've defined `related_name` explicitly on your ManyToMany fields, so that is the accessor you should use:

```
print s.students.all()
```

Not that the actual names you've used don't make much sense; the reverse relationship is not "students", it's "sections as a student".